# Receiving error Error: Unable to create directory after Grunt update

Tags: node.js, angular, gruntjs

Have updated grunt from `1.0.4` to `1.3.0`, after upgrade if i run grunt , receiving the following error.

```
Verifying property mkdir.doc exists in config...OK
File: [no files]
Options: mode=null, create=["./build/documentation"]
Options: mode=null, create=["./build/documentation"]
Creating "./build/documentation"...ERROR
>> Error: Unable to create directory "./build/documentation" (Error code: ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE).
Warning: Mkdir operation failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Gone through this link https://github.com/SAP/cloud-mta-build-tool/issues/857 but couldn't get the solution. Please share your ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

Its because of grunt-mkdir npm.

After adding mode of directory creation its worked

```
mkdir: { 
abc: {
            options: {
                mode: 0777,
                create: ['./build/abc']
            }
        }
}
```

Issue: https://github.com/rubenv/grunt-mkdir/issues/7